# When trying to create a new date by adding 4 years to an established date, both dates are changed (GregorianCalendar)

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

Full disclosure, this is homework, but only a very small part of an assignment that I can't figure out why it's not working. Here is the assignment text:

> Create a CollegeStudent class.  This class will contain data fields
> that hold a student's first name, last name, enrollment date, and
> projected graduation date, using the GregorianCalendar class for each
> date.  Provide get() and set() methods for each field.  Also provide a
> constructor that requires first and last names and enrollment date,
> and sets the project graduation date to exactly four years after
> enrolment.  Save the class as CollegeStudent.java.
>
> Create an interactive application that prompts the user for data for two
> CollegeStudent objects.  Prompt the user for first name, last name,
> enrollment month, enrollment day, and enrollment year for each
> CollegeStudent, and then instantiate the objects.  Display all the
> values, including the projected graduation dates.  Save the
> application as TestCollegeStudent.java

I've been able to do everything it asks, except when I try to calculate the graduation date, it adds 4 years to the enrollment date value as well. Here is my CollegeStudent class:

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class CollegeStudent {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    GregorianCalendar enrollmentDate;
    GregorianCalendar graduationDate;
    
    
    // Constructor requiring first name, last name, and enrollment date
    public CollegeStudent(String first, String last, GregorianCalendar enrollment) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        enrollmentDate = enrollment;
        
        // Set graduationDate to enrollmentDate, then add 4 years
        graduationDate = enrollment;
        graduationDate.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 4);
    }
    // Get and Set firstName
    public void setFirstName(String first) {
        firstName = first;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    
    // Get and Set lastName
    public void setLastName(String last) {
        lastName = last;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    
    // Get and Set enrollmentDate
    public void setEnrollmentDate(GregorianCalendar enrollment) {
        enrollmentDate = enrollment;
    }
    public GregorianCalendar getEnrollmentDate(){
        return enrollmentDate;
    }
    
    // Get and Set graduationDate
    public void setGraduationDate(GregorianCalendar graduation) {
        graduationDate = graduation;
    }
    public GregorianCalendar getGraduationDate() {
        return graduationDate;
    }

}
```

My TestCollegeStudent.java displays both the enrollmentDate and graduationDate and they both show the same date 4 years after the initial enrollmentDate entered by the user. If I remove the line where I added 4 years to the graduationDate, they both display as the initial enrollmentDate. I feel like I'm missing some very simple syntax issue, but I haven't been able to figure out what it is.

Comment: The `GregorianCalendar` class is poorly designed and for that reason was replaced by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) with Java 8 nearly 7 years ago. Teachers who still ask homework assignments using `GregorianCaelendar` deserve to be sacked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because of the following assignment inside the constructor:

```
graduationDate = enrollment;
```

This assignment makes `graduationDate` reference to the same instance of `Calendar` which is being referenced by `enrollment` and therefore a change in the instance brought through any of the references will cause the result to be the same for both the references.

You can understand it with the following example:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar enrollment = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar graduationDate = enrollment;
        System.out.println(enrollment.getTime());
        System.out.println(graduationDate.getTime());

        graduationDate.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 4);
        System.out.println(enrollment.getTime());
        System.out.println(graduationDate.getTime());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sat Jan 16 15:31:29 GMT 2021
Sat Jan 16 15:31:29 GMT 2021
Thu Jan 16 15:31:29 GMT 2025
Thu Jan 16 15:31:29 GMT 2025
```

In order to deal with this situation, `graduationDate` needs to reference a copy (clone) of the instance being referenced `enrollment` so that any changes brought through the reference, `graduationDate` will only be applicable to the clone.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar enrollment = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar graduationDate = (Calendar)enrollment.clone();// You have to do this
        System.out.println(enrollment.getTime());
        System.out.println(graduationDate.getTime());

        graduationDate.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 4);
        System.out.println(enrollment.getTime());
        System.out.println(graduationDate.getTime());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sat Jan 16 15:30:34 GMT 2021
Sat Jan 16 15:30:34 GMT 2021
Sat Jan 16 15:30:34 GMT 2021
Thu Jan 16 15:30:34 GMT 2025
```

By the way, the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Check out **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)** for step-by-step tutorial and examples of using the *java.time* API (the modern date-time API).

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I thought I was just passing the value of enrollment to graduationDate, not a reference to the instance. I still get confused with passing values vs passing references, but I understand what was happening now. Creating a clone of enrollmentDate fixed the issue. Thanks again for the thorough explanation!

Comment: When it comes to objects (including arrays), you are always assigning a reference, not the value. Only with primitives (like `int`) it’s always a value.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for putting additional information which will benefit the future visitors of this answer. I can also see that you have added yet another good answer using the modern date-time API.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do `graduationDate = enrollment` graduationDate is now pointing to the enrollment object, and every change you make on any of then will reflect on the other, since they are **the same** object.

What you really want is to create a **new** calendar that is based on another calendar, which should be `graduationDate = (GregorianCalendar)enrollment.clone();`

Answer (score 1):

There is already a good answer present in this thread. I am adding my contribution. The main source of the problem is this line where graduationDate is referring to enrollment

`graduationDate = enrollment`

You can also try this:

```java
// Set graduationDate to enrollmentDate, then add 4 years
graduationDate = new GregorianCalendar(); // New object
graduationDate.setTime(enrollmentDate.getTime()); // Update time
graduationDate.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 4); // add years
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

For your assignment it probably won’t go, but everyone else should use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for date work. *And!* With java.time it’s virtually impossible to make the error you are asking about.

```
    LocalDate enrollmentDate = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.JANUARY, 4);
    LocalDate graduationDate = enrollmentDate.plusYears(4);
    
    System.out.format("Enrolled: %s. Projected graduation: %s.%n", enrollmentDate, graduationDate);
```

Output is:

> Enrolled: 2021-01-04. Projected graduation: 2025-01-04.

### Going to the border of the requirements

If you want to teach your teacher how this should be done and still keep the requirement that the fields have type `GregorianCalendar` … (1) I can’t say whether this is advisable at your school. (2) It will be a compromise, that is, no ideal solution, with the advantages of java.time and the disadvantage of mixed APIs and unnecessary conversions. Here goes:

```
public class CollegeStudent {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    GregorianCalendar enrollmentDate;
    GregorianCalendar graduationDate;
    
    // Constructor requiring first name, last name, and enrollment date
    public CollegeStudent(String first, String last,
            int enrollmentYear, int enrollmentMonth, int enrollmentDay) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        ZonedDateTime enrollmentZdt
                = LocalDate.of(enrollmentYear, enrollmentMonth, enrollmentDay)
                        .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        enrollmentDate = GregorianCalendar.from(enrollmentZdt);
        
        // Add 4 years to enrollmentZdt, then convert so it can be assigned to graduationDate
        ZonedDateTime graduationZdt = enrollmentZdt.plusYears(4);
        graduationDate = GregorianCalendar.from(graduationZdt);
    }
    
    // Getters and setters …
}
```

To try it out:

```
    CollegeStudent student = new CollegeStudent("Wes", "Hampton", 2021, 1, 16);
    System.out.println("Enrolled:      " + student.getEnrollmentDate().toZonedDateTime());
    System.out.println("Will graduate: " + student.getGraduationDate().toZonedDateTime());
```

Output in my time zone:

> ```
> Enrolled:      2021-01-16T00:00+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> Will graduate: 2025-01-16T00:00+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> ```

### Links

- This would make for a good read for your teacher. [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- A related question: [Changing values in an object makes changes to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456992/changing-values-in-an-object-makes-changes-to-another)